# React App component not rendering based on conditional logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

The logic of this component looks good to me.

- Assuming `isReceivedSession` is true, a `<ReactFragment/>` renders; if not, a `<Spinner/>` should render
- Within the fragment, if `isLoadingApp || isLoadingAuth` is truthy, a `<Spinner/>` component should render; if the statement is not truthy, a line and the router are returned and render.

But even when `isLoadingApp` logs true in the console, the spinner never shows up.  I just see a fragment (nothing) or the expected line and router navigation path.

When `isLoadingApp` evaluates to true, a spinner component should be visible.

I feel like I'm missing something deeper here...where is the flaw in the logic?

```
const App = ({ classes }: IProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isReceivedSession, setIsReceivedSession] = useState(false);

  const isLoadingAuth: boolean = useSelector(authIsLoadingSelector);
  const isLoadingApp: boolean = useSelector(appIsLoadingSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const sessionData = await CognitoClient.currentSession();
        const currentSessionToken = sessionData.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        if (currentSessionToken) {
          dispatch(authActions.setAuthStatus(AUTH_STATUS.LOGGED_IN));
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReceivedSession(true);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  //all logging values properly
  console.log("isReceivedSession", isReceivedSession);
  console.log("isLoadingApp ", isLoadingApp);
  console.log("isLoadingAuth ", isLoadingAuth)

  return isReceivedSession ? (
    //spinner never renders even when isLoadingApp is true
    <Fragment>
      {isLoadingApp ||

        (isLoadingAuth && <Spinner size={48} className={classes.spinner} />)}
      <HeaderLine />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={APP_AUTH_PATH()} component={SignInScreen} />
          <PrivateRoute
            path={APP_DASHBOARD_PATH()}
            component={DashboardScreen}
            authenticationPath={APP_AUTH_PATH()}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path={APP_LANDING_PATH()}
            render={() => <Redirect to={APP_DASHBOARD_PATH()} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  ) : (
    <Spinner size={48} className={classes.spinner} />
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Is the local `isReceivedSession` state "masking" when the loading spinner should display? In other words, is `isReceivedSession` set true at the same time any of the loading states are toggled false? Is it possible to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Only "odd" thing I see is that `isLoadingApp || (isLoadingAuth && <Spinner size={48} className={classes.spinner} />)` should probably be `(isLoadingApp || isLoadingAuth) && <Spinner size={48} className={classes.spinner} />` so if either of the `isLoadingX` states is truthy the spinner will display. The parenthesis form an incorrect logical grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical OR operator "||" doesn't look at the second condition whenever the first condition is already true.

Comment: Thanks, noted; in this particular case, if the first condition ```isLoadingApp``` condition is true that should still return a render of the spinner.  So the problem remains.

Comment: I'm saying if isLoadingApp is true, the way it's setup now it will not look at the second condition or the spinner component. Thats why the spinner doesn't get printed.

Comment: Ah yes yes.  @jmelger @DrewReese you both helped! The way it was set up, given the operator precedence, even with the perentheses around ```(isLoadingAuth && <Spinner/>)``` the returned value of everything would be simply ```true``` any time ```isLoadingApp``` is true.  The spinner would have only rendered if ```isLoadingApp``` is false and ```isLoadingAuth``` is true, which would be rare and not what I was aiming for.

Comment: Glad we could be of help mate